# How can I iterate through the pages of a website using Python?

Tags: python, web, loops

I'm new to software development, and I'm not sure how to go about this. I want to visit every page of a website and grab a specific bit of data from each one. My problem is, I don't know how to iterate through all of the existing pages without knowing the individual urls ahead of time. For example, I want to visit every page whose url starts with

> "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/"

Is there a way to compile a list and then iterate through that, or is it possible to do this without creating a giant list of urls?

Answer (score 5):

Try [Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html).

It handles all of the crawling for you and lets you focus on processing the data, not extracting it. Instead of copy-pasting the code already in the tutorial, I'll leave it to you to read it.

Comment: +1 for Scrapy. Has a bit of a learning curve, but easy to use once you get a hang of it.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll try that. My problem isn't really processing the data, but the search for it. I suppose if I had know the technical terms, I could have looked this up myself. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To grab a specific bit of data from a web site you could use some web scraping tool e.g., [scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html).

If required data is generated by javascript then you might need browser-like tool such as [Selenium WebDriver](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) and implement crawling of the links by hand.

Answer (score -2):

For example, you can make a simple for loop, like this:

```
def webIterate():
    base_link = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/"
    for i in xrange(24):
        print "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/%d" % (i)
```

The output will be:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/0
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3
...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23
```

It's just an example. You can pass numbers of questions and make with them whatever you want

Comment: I think StackOverflow was just an example. Other websites don't have such a well-defined URL scheme and need to be parsed via crawling.

Comment: Maibe. But it would be really much easier to help author if he will tell us the real example of the site, needed to be aggregated:)

Comment: I see how that would work, but stackoverflow was just an example, the site I'm trying to search doesn't use numerical values to number pages.

Comment: Give us an example and we'll try to find out the solution:)